# Is this inequality possible?

Tags: inequality

For $ c> b>a>0 $
Is this inequality true?
$$ c^2+ab> ac+bc $$

If yes can anybody please provide hint so I can solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we have $$c^2-ac+ab-bc>0$$ and this is equivalent to
$$c(c-a)+b(a-c)>0$$ and this is equivalent to
$$(c-a)(c-b)>0$$
this is true, since we have $$c>b>a>0$$

Comment: I think it's really a ridiculous attempt but I tried differentiating both sides with respect to c. And approached the inequality $2c>a+b$ which is really easy to prove. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(c-b)c > (c-b)a$$

This is because $c-b > 0$ and $c > a$